# DocuSign JWT Auth Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Error with response Body C# sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate docusign rest api in my web application where my .net version is 4.7.2. I have used docusign dll of version 5.2.0.

I am trying to get access token using jwt auth type. So I set up app, integrator key and rsa private key for app.

```
                var scopes = new List<string>{"impersonation","signature"}
          
                string directorypath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + "Files/");
                string fileNameOnly = "docusign_private_key.txt";

                var filePath = Path.Combine(directorypath, fileNameOnly);
                var privateKeyBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                var apiClient = new ApiClient();
                var authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken
                    (
                        clientId: credential.ClientID,
                        userId: credential.UserID,
                        oauthBasePath: credential.BasePath,
                        privateKeyBytes: privateKeyBytes,
                        expiresInHours: 1,
                        scopes: scopes
                    );
```

I used integrator key as clientId, API Username as UserId, https://demo.docusign.net/restapi as oauthBasePath. Is there anything I forgot to mention or make mistake? I am not able to get access token. It throws ApiException with message `Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code Error with response Body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate JWT token in demo environment, change your oauthBasePath to **account-d.docusign.com** ( authentication server ). You can read more [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/). https://demo.docusign.net/restapi is the application base path you can use to make calls to all eSignature endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string AuthenticateWithJWT()
    {
        var devPlaceholder = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"; // dev
        var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(devPlaceholder);
        string ik = "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww";
        string userId = "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww";
        string authServer = "account-d.docusign.com";
        List<string> scopes = new List<string>
        {
            "signature",
            "impersonation"
        };

        OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = docuSignClient.RequestJWTUserToken(ik,
                        userId,
                        authServer,
                        System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\mtishad\source\repos\PIMS\Application\PIMS.MVCClient\docusign_private_key.txt"),
                        1,
                        scopes);

        string accessToken = authToken.access_token;
        docuSignClient.SetOAuthBasePath(authServer);
        OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = docuSignClient.GetUserInfo(authToken.access_token);

        var account = userInfo.Accounts.FirstOrDefault();

        string accountId = account.AccountId;
        string baseUri = account.BaseUri + "/restapi";
        return accessToken;
    }
```

Help-
I get 500 with no response body

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35300333)